# Second stage doesnt recognize the installation of the first stage in multistage builds docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a container image that is huge 3GB so I have googled how to reduce the size of images and apparently using multistage builds is helpful. But I wasn't able to know how to integrate it in my dockerfile because it seems that the second stage is not able to find all the installations I have installed in the first stage.
Any help, please.

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as build
# WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential curl \
  python3-pip python3 python3-venv python3-apsw \
  swig \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /workspaces/AutoML/
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
ENV LOGGER_DEBUG=True
RUN python3 -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
COPY ./config/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel && \
  hash pip && \
  python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir torch==1.9.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir numpy
COPY ./config/lib ./lib
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir shap==0.36.0 && \
  python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir dask[distributed] --upgrade \
  dask[bag] --upgrade \
  autogluon==0.0.15 \
  mxnet \
  ./lib/*
  FROM python:3 
COPY --from=build /opt/venv /opt/venv
# shap==0.36.0

COPY ./src ./src/
# RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir ConfigSpace==0.4.14 \
#   -e ./automl/ \
#   -e ./automlserver/
ENV PYTHONPATH="/workspaces/AutoML/:${PYTHONPATH}"
RUN mkdir logs
EXPOSE 80
# for debugging environment
CMD [ "python3", "/src/service/automlserver/launch.py", "-ip", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "80"]
```

Comment: What error or problem are you having?  In the first stage you add the virtual environment to `$PATH`, do you need to repeat that in the second stage?  (Why are so many things missing from your `requirements.txt` file?)

Comment: The problem i am facing is when i run my container I have an error that some packages are not installed, while its installed in the first stage but not copied to the second stage in dockerfile. @DavidMaze

Comment: I have excluded some packages from the requirements.txt because it was somehow throwing an error when doing the installations